# можно ли спросить у rsync-сервера на удаленном хосте хеш-сумму директории

Tags: node.js, файловая-система, rsync

есть набор `удаленных` хостов на которых крутится `rsync-сервер`. Он принимает и складывает папки с файлами в определенную директорию.

такие файлы и папки отправляются с сервера на `nodejs` с помощью `rsync` клиента.

**Вопрос:** можно ли со стороны сервера nodejs спросить хеш-сумму какой то конкретной директории у rsync-сервера на удаленном хосте?

**цель** Необходимо для реализации мониторинга версий бизнес а также системных решений, по сути система обновления с обратной связью. Просто в информационной системе была уже реализована передача необходимых файлов на удаленные сервера компании с помощью `rsync`.

хеш-сумма нужна чтобы сравнить с хеш-суммой записанный в бд сервиса системы обновления, таким образом выяснить верная ли версия того или иного отчета 1с, например, в филиале.

**upd:** Может посоветуйте другую утилиту которая бы справилась с подобной задачей если ее спросить? (всегда есть вариант написать свою, но хотелось бы оставить велики на потом)

**upd:** А если пытаться отдать, на удаленный сервер rsync, файл и в случае если он у него есть - не вернет ли он в качестве обратной связи что то типа "ей у меня такое уже есть, в передаче нет необходимости"? Это по сути было бы решением проблемы, так как скорее всего rsync сравнивает по хеш-суммам, и в этом случае можно было бы понять что все ок, а если нет, то мы, во первых, знаем об этом, а во вторых, сразу передаем правильные файлы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На данный момент сервер nodejs отправляет файлы с помощью [пакета rsync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rsync) это выглядит примерно так:

```
var Rsync = require('rsync');

// Build the command 
var rsync = new Rsync()
  .shell('ssh')
  .flags('az')
  .source('/path/to/source')
  .destination('server:/path/to/destination');

// Execute the command 
rsync.execute(function(error, code, cmd) {
    // we're done 
});
```

Comment: а с какой целью вам нужен hash? инересуюсь по той причине, что похоже на наличие «[проблемы молотка](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/709/178576)»

Comment: `hash` нужен чтобы `сравнить` с hash записанный в `бд` сервиса системы обновления, таким образом выяснить `верная ли версия` того или иного отчета 1с, например, `в филиале`.

Comment: к сожалению, из вопроса не понятно, что и где у вас хранится, какие программы у каких запрашивают информацию. поэтому лишь предполагаю: где-то далеко (и в разных местах) хранятся файлы. они не изменяются и не переименовываются во время хранения. вам надо идентифицировать эти файлы. наименее затратно — хранить уникальную информацию (ту же хэш-сумму) в именах файлов. по крайней мере это не требует **повторных** вычислений хэш-сумм.

Comment: если файлы (по каким-то эзотерическим причинам) нельзя переименовывать, то рядом с ними можно хранить файл с хэш-суммами (по строке на каждый хранимый файл: путь к  файлу, пробел, хэш-сумма). тогда вам 1) не нужно время для вычисления хэш-суммы каждый раз, когда потребуется идентифицировать файл и 2) реализовывать в программе rsync новую функциональность, которая изложена в заголовке вопроса.

Comment: но в таком случае я не смогу гарантировать что файлы не изменялись?

Comment: а разве бывают какие-то случаи, когда вы сможете гарантировать, что файлы не изменялись?

Comment: да если мне известен хеш, и при необходимости я могу получить этот хеш еще раз для сравнения с тем который я записал в бд когда отправлял файлы rsync-серверу. если они одинаковы я могу гарантировать что файлы не менялись.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хеш-сумму директории спросить нельзя, но можно спросить какие файлы изменились не выполняя собственно операции копирования. Нужно лишь указать флаг `dry-run`:

```
rsync.set('dry-run'); // оно же rsync.dry();
```

Затем [из вывода команды](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rsync#outputstdouthandler-stderrhandler) получить список изменившихся файлов. Если вы явно этого не запрещали, то сравнение будет происходить именно так как вы хотите, то есть [с помощью контрольных сумм](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync#.D0.90.D0.BB.D0.B3.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.BC).

Получить только список файлов без ничего можете указав [опцию `out-format`](https://superuser.com/a/936298/16120) например в таком виде:

```
out-format="%f"
```

Comment: да, так можно. Если смотреть в рамках поставленного вопроса то ваш ответ наиболее точный. Хоть в реальном проекте я пошел по пути который посоветовали ранее(вариант держать по nodejs-серверу на каждом удаленном сервере более гибкий).  Поэтому я ставлю ему +1.

Answer (score 1):

> можно ли со стороны сервера nodejs спросить хеш какой то конкретной директории у rsync-сервера на удаленном хосте?

нет, так нельзя. можно только сделать хеш самому.

### Первый вариант: [hash-files](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hash-files)

#### Установка

```
npm install hash-files
```

#### Использование

```
var hashFiles = require('hash-files');

// options is optional 
hashFiles(options, function(error, hash) {
    // hash will be a string if no error occurred 
});
```

или в командной строке:

```
$ ./bin/hash-files -f '["package.json"]' -a sha256
a29089cc5e3f8bf6ae15ea6b9cd5eaefb14bbb12e3baa2c56ee5c21422250c75
```

### Второй вариант: сам [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html)

**crypto.createHash(algorithm)**

```
const filename = process.argv[2];
const crypto = require('crypto');
const fs = require('fs');

const hash = crypto.createHash('sha256');

const input = fs.createReadStream(filename);
input.on('readable', () => {
  var data = input.read();
  if (data)
    hash.update(data);
  else {
    console.log(`${hash.digest('hex')} ${filename}`);
  }
});
```

Comment: совершенно верно, таким образом я получу хеш перед тем как отправлять на удаленный хост. rsync-сервер на удаленном хосте принимает и пишет в свою рабочую диреткторию. конечно можно развернуть на удаленных хостах по `node-серверу` и слушать своим api запрос на снятие хеш. В таком случае ваше решение возможно. Или вы не это имели в виду?

Comment: да. так. я не представляю как по другому сделать. в смысле как можно с помощью nodejs отправить запрос к сервису rsync на удаленной машине

Comment: ну например с помощью https://www.npmjs.com/package/rsync

Comment: внедрение на каждом удаленном хосте по nodejs-серверу выглядит разумной идеей, в конце концов кто знает что мне еще нужно будет спросить у удаленных машин филиалов, а ноду можно будет научить.

Answer (score 1):

насколько мне известно, ни одна реализация *rsync*-сервера/клиента не поддерживает требуемой вами возможности. другие задачи они решают.

но, судя по приведённому вами коду, для связи с серверами используется протокол *ssh*. следовательно, вы можете просто запустить программу подсчёта контрольных сумм нужных файлов непосредственно на сервере

```
md5sum /путь/к/файлу1 /путь/к/файлу2 /путь/к/каталогу/*
```

и проанализировать ответ:

```
хэш-сумма  /путь/к/файлу1
хэш-сумма  /путь/к/файлу2
хэш-сумма  /путь/к/каталогу/файл3
хэш-сумма  /путь/к/каталогу/файл4
...
```

программа `md5sum` служит для вычисления контрольной суммы по алгоритму *md5*, но в пакет *gnu/coreutils* входит [множество других программ](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Summarizing-files.html#Summarizing-files), работающих и с другими крипто-алгоритмами.

---

реализаций же клиентов *ssh* для `node.js` более чем много: [раз](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-ssh), [два](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ssh), [три](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2) и т.д.